# NSNumberFormatter's inconsistent behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumberformatter

When I set the `usesSignificantDigits` property to `true`, the `NSNumberFormatter` won't obey the `maximumFractionDigits`. I think this also applies to `minimumFractionDigits`.

For example:

```
let formatter: NSNumberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.allowsFloats = true
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
formatter.usesSignificantDigits = true

let result = formatter.stringFromNumber(1.2345)
```

The above code returns `"1.2345"` as result. The intended result is `"1.23"`. When I set the `usesSignificantDigits` to `false`, it works.

This is contradicting the statement in the developer reference for `usesSignificantDigits`:

> Determines whether the receiver uses minimum and maximum significant digits properties.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `usesSignificantDigits` controls the use of `minimumSignificantDigits` and `maximumSignificantDigits`, not `minimumFractionDigits` and `maximumFractionDigits`. You did not set `maximumSignificantDigits` in your code so it will use its default value (which seems to be 6).

Consider this enhancement of your original code:

```
let formatter: NSNumberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.allowsFloats = true
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle

// Makes formatter use maximumSignificantDigits
formatter.usesSignificantDigits = true

println(formatter.maximumSignificantDigits) // Prints 6

// Will use 6 significant digits, hence "1.2345"
let result = formatter.stringFromNumber(1.2345)
```

If you don't want to use the value of `maximumSignificantDigits`, you should not set `usesSignificantDigits` to `true`. This behavior matches the description in the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSNumberFormatter/usesSignificantDigits).

Comment: That was so dumb of me! Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

- if `usesSignificantDigits` is `true` the formatter is using `minimumSignificantDigits` and `maximumSignificantDigits`

  The default value for `minimumSignificantDigits` is 1.
  The default value for `maximumSignificantDigits` is 6.
- if `usesSignificantDigits` is `false` the formatter is using `maximumFractionDigits`

So the behavior is correct.

Comment: Thanks @vadian. That really helped!